# functions passed as props are invoked regardless

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm developing an application that has the following component hierarchy (courtesy ProReact)

KanbanContainer => KanbanBoard => List => Card => CheckList

KanbanContainer contains methods that need to be passed down to the CheckList component (as that component has all the ui controls). The methods in the KanbanContainer are defined as follows

```
class KanbanBoardContainer extends Component {
  state = { cards: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ cards: API.getTasks() });
  }
  addTask = (cardId, taskName) => {
    console.log(taskName, " invoked for cardId =", cardId);
  };
  deleteTask = (cardId, taskId, taskIndex) => {
    console.log("deleteTask invoked for cardId = ", cardId);
  };
  toggleTask = (cardId, taskId, taskIndex) => {
    console.log("toggleTask invoked fpr cardId = ", cardId);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <KanbanBoard
        cards={this.state.cards}
        taskCallbacks={{
          toggleTask: this.toggleTask,
          addTask: this.addTask,
          deleteTask: this.deleteTask
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In all the other components, the taskCallbacks is simply passed on via props. For example:

```
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let cards = this.props.cards.map(c => {
      return (
        <Card
          id={c.id}
          key={c.id}
          title={c.title}
          description={c.description}
          color={c.color}
          tasks={c.tasks}
          taskCallbacks={this.props.taskCallbacks}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="list">
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        {cards}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the final component, the functions passed in via props are attached to the ui controls such as checkbox and a link.

```
class CheckList extends Component {
  checkInputKeyPress = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.props.taskCallbacks.addTask(this.props.cardId, event.target.value);
      event.target.value = "";
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { deleteTask, toggleTask } = this.props.taskCallbacks;
    let tasks = this.props.tasks.map((t, index) => (
      <li key={t.id}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name=""
          id=""
          defaultChecked={t.done}
          onChange={toggleTask(this.props.cardId, t.id, index)}
        />{" "}
        {t.name}{" "}
        <a
          href="#"
          onClick={deleteTask(this.props.cardId, t.id, index)}
        />
      </li>
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{tasks}</ul>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Key in a task and hit enter"
          onKeyPress={this.checkInputKeyPress}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However when I load the application, the functions get called "on load" and nothing happens when the controls are clicked. Only the addTask() gets called when you type in the textfield and hit enter. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using:

```
onClick={deleteTask(this.props.cardId, t.id, index)}
```

The function will be invoked in place. Try switching for:

```
onClick={() => deleteTask(this.props.cardId, t.id, index)}
```

For clarity, `deleteTask` is a reference to a function, `deleteTask()` invokes a function. In a situation where you need to invoke the function (for example, to pass arguments) then the pattern above is an anonymous function that calls your `deleteTask` function.

Comment: It isn't the best idea to have function declaration inside your render as it will create a new function in memory every time you re-render. This can bloat your memory usage and make more work for garbage collection. Check out [this article](https://alligator.io/react/new-way-to-handle-events/).

Comment: True, but there is a [counter point](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578).

Comment: With fat arrow it worked. However can i implement it without the fat arrow ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in the last component that calls the prop function with the appropriate arguments. That is, don't invoke a function directly from onClick/onChange, becase those props expect a reference to a function, not the result of invoking a function.

Most importantly, you should check out the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in order to avoid passing down so many props.

Comment: Thanks for the contextAPI suggestion! will check it out